# Xamarin WPF doesn't reflect code changes without rebuild

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've configured a Xamarin Forms WPF platform project using this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/other/wpf

It's working, but when I make any change in my Xamarin.Forms class library project (either code or XAML), the change is not reflected in the actual WPF app.
Only when I manually rebuild the Xamarin.Forms project, I see the changes reflected.

This is not happening in the UWP project, only in the WPF project.

Comment: Try to update your visual-studio.

Comment: It's updated, doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it by adding the following to the csproj file of the WPF project:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <DisableFastUpToDateCheck>true</DisableFastUpToDateCheck>
</PropertyGroup>
```